# How to show inline details for html table with a toggle button using typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html-table

I need to create a toggle button for my table (to show/hide) more details of selected row.

Given this is my table:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor='let c of companies'>
            <td><button id="{{c.companyId}}" (click)="showDetail()">Details</button> </td>
            <td>{{ c.company}}</td>
            <td>{{ c.contact}}</td>
            <td>{{ c.country }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

When I click on "Details" button, need to show details inline in the table. This is kind of master detail grid approach in Kendo Grid. Any better approach using Angular2 & typescript to show details in easy way?

Comment: Can you create a working example in jsbin or jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor='let c of companies'>
        <tr>
            <td><button id="{{c.companyId}}" (click)="c.details = !c.details">Details</button> </td>
            <td>{{ c.company}}</td>
            <td>{{ c.contact}}</td>
            <td>{{ c.country }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="c.details">
            <td>Details go here</td>
            <td>More details</td>
            <td>More details</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

A small change from birwin's answer, as you cannot use `template` here without a directive, so use `ng-container` instead.

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let c of companies'>
    <tr>
        <td><button id="{{c.companyId}}" (click)="c.details = !c.details">Details</button> </td>
        <td>{{ c.company}}</td>
        <td>{{ c.contact}}</td>
        <td>{{ c.country }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="c.details">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QWl7JLcGTokkT1rYHXDs?p=preview)